# nunit how to have a once off setup method (for all tests)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit

I need a once-off setup method, called only once, across all test fixtures.

This is to setup common stuff like AutoMapper, some mocks used by everything.

How can I do this? (And I'm not talking about TestFixtureSetup)

Comment: You want `SetUpFixtureAttribute`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993045/can-i-have-code-that-executes-before-and-after-tests-are-run-by-nunit/2993086#2993086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have all your test classes inherit from a base test class, and do your setup in the constructor.

```
public class TestBase {
     public TestBase() {
       // Global setup
     }
}

public class MyTest : TestBase {
     // Tests
}
```